# Better to use icons or text to present options on product listing

Tags: touch-screen, mobile-application

[image]

On my app, when a user taps an item,  some icons (favorite, add to cart, more detail) pop out below giving them some additional features. Now my concern is that these icons can be difficult to interpret, so is it a good idea to substitute these for text instead? How would I present this with the limited real estate that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach to handle this would be to do an overlay which gives you the real estate to just not only favorite an item but also show the other options as well. Here are some examples of apps who have used overlays well to highlight the different options available

[image]

The example above shows all the different options in a overlay at the bottom which also gives it a lot of real estate to see the different choices. I would also recommend adding text since the icons themselves are not visually intuitive!

---

### The examples below all also use popovers an option to convey more information while not crowding the screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2B3c.png).

[image]

[image]